# What does mapFn represent in map(mapFn, thisArg)?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

In Array.from docs it says :

> Array.from() has an optional parameter mapFn, which allows you to
> execute a map function on each element of the array (or subclass
> object) that is being created.

I wanted to see what's inside `mapFn`.

I can see array with values if I use `.map((_, value) => value )`

Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg)

```js
const anArray = Array.from({
    length: 5
  })
   //.map((wh, value) => value ) //prints out values 0,1,2,3,4 
   .map((wh, value) => wh ) //undefined
   //.map((value) => value )  //undefined

   
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = anArray;

console.log(anArray);
```

```css
#result {
  padding: 2rem;
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<p id="result" />
```

### What does wh Function Parameter represents in my code?

Comment: are you talking about [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Comment: Array.from(obj) -- `Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg)`

Comment: Try with `Array.from('abc')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) supports passing in an optional *mapping function* which is what `mapFn` is in the MDN documentation. For instance, supposed you have an array-like NodeList of DOM elements and you want their text as an array:

```js
const result = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(".x"), // The array-like object (arrayLike in the MDN docs)
    elm => elm.textContent           // The mapping function (mapFn in the MDN docs)
);
console.log(result); // ["one", "two", "three"]
```

```html
<div class="x">one</div>
<div class="x">two</div>
<div class="x">three</div>
```

But your code is using the [`map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), not the `Array.from` mapping parameter. `map` *also* accepts a mapping function.

> What does wh Function Parameter represents in my code?

In your `.map((wh, value) => wh )` code, your function (`(wh, value) => wh`) is passed each array entry's value one at a time, and your function is using the `wh` parameter to receive them. (The `value` parameter receives the index of the entry, so `value` isn't an ideal name for it.) That particular `map` doesn't do anything because you're returning the same value you're receiving.

Here's a more typical usage of `map`, in this case converting numeric strings to numbers:

```js
const original = ["42", "37", "14"];
const numbers = original.map(str => str === "" ? NaN : Number(str));
// mapFn −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
console.log(numbers); // [42, 37, 14] (as numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) has a built-in mapping with the second parameter for the mapping function.

This function follows the same signature as the one for [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) without the third parameter for the original array:

```
(value, index) => {
    // function body
    return someValue;
}
```

```js
const
    anArray = Array.from(
        { length: 5 },
        (value, index) => index
    );
   
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = anArray;

console.log(anArray);
```

```html
<p id="result" />
```

Comment: (FWIW, TC39 did kick around providing the array-like as a third argument to the mapping function, but decided to avoid that complexity.)